# Sonar: Cannot process new projects after deletion of an old project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I had a nice smooth SonarQube server v5.3. Everything was running fine. Then today I decided to delete some projects that I didn't want. The deletion went ok, or at least I thought it did. They disappeared from the GUI.

I have even checked in the DB and they don't show up with this command:

```
select * from projects where kee like '%sonar%'
```

The problem is after I deleted these projects, when I try to run a sonar analysis again, a project is only Provisioned, but the analysis is not run. I get a DB error when I go to

Administration > Background Tasks > Logs

The error is:

```
2016.05.10 15:59:43 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Execute component visitors | time=6135ms
2016.05.10 15:59:43 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute measure variations | time=1ms
2016.05.10 15:59:43 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Computes Quality Gate measures | time=1ms
2016.05.10 15:59:43 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute Quality profile measures | time=18ms
2016.05.10 15:59:43 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Generate Quality profile events | time=4ms
2016.05.10 15:59:43 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Generate Quality gate events | time=3ms
2016.05.10 15:59:44 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVSa9zwoeZCFdUKsTOSM
org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException: Visit failed for Component {key=com.som.lan:lan-biz:src/main/java/sb1/biz/financing/demo,type=DIRECTORY}  located com.som.lan:lan-biz(type=MODULE)->com.som:lan(type=MODULE)->com.som:modules(type=MODULE)->bm-master_feature_dig-9129-javascript-in-sonar(type=PROJECT)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException.rethrowOrWrap(VisitException.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:52) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep.execute(PersistComponentsStep.java:77) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:72) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
```

#### Error updating database. Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SONAR.PROJECTS_KEE) violated

#### The error may involve org.sonar.db.component.ComponentMapper.insert-Inline

#### The error occurred while setting parameters

#### Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SONAR.PROJECTS_KEE) violated

```
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:154) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:141) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.db.component.ComponentDao.insert(ComponentDao.java:282) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.persistComponent(PersistComponentsStep.java:172) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.persistAndPopulateCache(PersistComponentsStep.java:164) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.visitDirectory(PersistComponentsStep.java:136) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitNode(PathAwareCrawler.java:102) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:67) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
... 26 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SONAR.PROJECTS_KEE) violated

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3714) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1378) ~[ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:44) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:69) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doUpdate(ReuseExecutor.java:50) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:105) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:71) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:152) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
... 37 common frames omitted
```

2016.05.10 15:59:44 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=bm-master_feature_dig-9129-javascript-in-sonar | id=AVSa9zwoeZCFdUKsTOSM | time=8689ms

This error shows up regardless of the project name. It seems like the modules are causing the unique constraint, not the project name itself.

I have tried:

- deleting the project using the GUI
- stopping sonar and restarting

I have not done anything manually in the DB apart from just looking at the tables to see if I could figure something out.

Any idea how I could get rid of this?

Thanks :)

Edit:

I am running sonar with maven like this:

```
mvn -e sonar:sonar \
-DskipTests \
-DXmx2g \
-DXX:MaxPermSize=1g \
-Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar.myserver.com \
-Dsonar.projectKey=${sonarProjectName} \
-Dsonar.projectName=${sonarProjectName} \
-Dsonar.projectVersion=${branch} \
-Dsonar.forceAnalysis=true \
-Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 \
-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true \
-Dsonar.sources=. \
-Dsonar.exclusions=**/target/**/*,**/src/lib/**/*,**/node_modules/**/* \
-Dsonar.test.exclusions=**/src/test/java/** \
-Dsonar.junit.reportsPath=**/target/surefire-reports \
-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=${WORKSPACE}/target/jacoco.exec \
-Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=${WORKSPACE}/target/jacoco-it.exec \
-Dsonar.java.binaries=**/target/classes \
-Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco \
-Dsonar.verbose=true
```

Because of the nature of the IT setup here, I cannot use Jenkins SonarQube Runner plug in. I use that in another project here and it runs flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue, but I don't know why the problem happened in the first place.

The resolution was to exclude the src demo directory, so I changed my exclusions to be :

```
    -Dsonar.exclusions=**/target/**/*,**/src/lib/**/*,**/node_modules/**/*,**/src/main/java/**/demo/**/* \
```

I'm not sure why the error showed up though. I later was looking over the Admin GUI on my sonar host, and I saw under  Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope > Files that I already had

```
**/demo/*.java
```

as a Source File Exclusion.

I wonder if that was what caused the Unique constraint error? Anyway, I hope I get a better response than this, so I know WHY the error happened.